# How should I contextualize this quote and understand its meaning?

Tags: existentialism, sartre, camus, absurdism

Jean- Paul Sartre once said about Camus: "I would call his pessimism 'solar' if you remember how much black there is in the sun."

Comment: It seems Sartre's judgment about Camus' pessimism compared to his own. Maybe useful [JEAN-PAUL SARTRE, EXPLIXATION DE L'ETRANGER (1947)](https://www.psychaanalyse.com/pdf/EXPLIXATION%20DE%20L%20ETRANGER%20-%20JEAN-PAUL%20SARTRE%201947%20(8%20pages%20-%20266%20ko).pdf)